# Convert character to ASCII code in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How can I convert a character to its ASCII code using JavaScript?

For example:

> get 10 from "\n".

Comment: Please note that the [String.prototype.charCodeAt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) method suggested in most answers will return the **UTF-16 code unit** (not even the full proper UTF-16 encoding due to historical reasons). Only the first 128 Unicode code points are a direct match of the ASCII character encoding.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález This is an importan caveat. How do I get the ASCII code instead, e.g. `128` for `€`?

Comment: @simlev ASCII does not have any `€` symbol, it was created decades before the currency. `128` is its encoding in Windows-1252. Converting between random encodings is a problem of its own.

Answer (score 1808, accepted):

```
"\n".charCodeAt(0);
```

Here is the documentation for [`charCodeAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt):

> The `charCodeAt()` method returns an integer between 0 and 65535 representing the UTF-16 code unit at the given index.
>
> The UTF-16 code unit matches the Unicode code point for code points which can be represented in a single UTF-16 code unit. If the Unicode code point cannot be represented in a single UTF-16 code unit (because its value is greater than `0xFFFF`) then the code unit returned will be the first part of a surrogate pair for the code point. If you want the entire code point value, use `codePointAt()`.

If you need to support non-BMP Unicode characters like U+1F602 , then don't use `charCodeAt`, as it will not return 128514 (or 0x1f602 in hexadecimal), it will give a result you don't expect:

```js
console.log("\u{1f602}".charCodeAt(0));
// prints 55357 , which is 0xd83d in hexadecimal
```

Comment: The opposite of this is `String.fromCharCode(10)`.

Comment: Fun fact: you don’t really need the `0` (first argument value) — just `"\n".charCodeAt()` will do.

Comment: @MathiasBynens: and fortunately this is documented: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt. "if it is not a number, it defaults to 0"

Comment: You should point out that unlike `String.fromCharCode( asciiNumVal )`, `stringInstance.charCodeAt( index )` is __not__ a static method of class String

Comment: @Mathias Bynens, It certainly does default to zero but I just ran a just out of interest test on performance and it performs **relatively badly compared using 0. http://jsperf.com/default-to-0-vs-0/4

** Its a relative difference only, either way its very very quick.

Comment: @wademontague I would have never thought to perf-test that. That's so ridiculous! Thanks for the results.

Comment: I think it's a bit clearer (readability wise) to specify the index instead of leaving it to defaults...but it's minor anyway

Comment: @MathiasBynens `charCodeAt()` with no arguments makes little sense

Comment: @developerbmw Try `"ABC".charCodeAt(0) // return 65` is just A ... position array, other position B is `"ABC".charCodeAt(1) // return 66`, i agre @Mathias is correct.

Comment: Apparently omitting the 0 is slower, if anyone cares. See royhowie's comment on Marco Altieri's answer below.

Comment: please don't just give the solution explain why it would work with a supportive answer

Comment: including 0 is now slower on Chrome 75 by 2% for anyone interested... interestingly, the .charCodeAt(1) was the most performant (.03% faster than no args)

Comment: `charCodeAt()` without argument gives an error in TypeScript.

Answer (score 496):

[`String.prototype.charCodeAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) can convert string characters to ASCII numbers. For example:

```
"ABC".charCodeAt(0) // returns 65
```

For opposite use [`String.fromCharCode(10)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) that convert numbers to equal ASCII character. This function can accept multiple numbers and join all the characters then return the string. Example:

```
String.fromCharCode(65,66,67); // returns 'ABC'
```

Here is a quick ASCII characters reference:

```
{
"31": "",      "32": " ",     "33": "!",     "34": "\"",    "35": "#",    
"36": "$",     "37": "%",     "38": "&",     "39": "'",     "40": "(",    
"41": ")",     "42": "*",     "43": "+",     "44": ",",     "45": "-",    
"46": ".",     "47": "/",     "48": "0",     "49": "1",     "50": "2",    
"51": "3",     "52": "4",     "53": "5",     "54": "6",     "55": "7",    
"56": "8",     "57": "9",     "58": ":",     "59": ";",     "60": "<",    
"61": "=",     "62": ">",     "63": "?",     "64": "@",     "65": "A",    
"66": "B",     "67": "C",     "68": "D",     "69": "E",     "70": "F",    
"71": "G",     "72": "H",     "73": "I",     "74": "J",     "75": "K",    
"76": "L",     "77": "M",     "78": "N",     "79": "O",     "80": "P",    
"81": "Q",     "82": "R",     "83": "S",     "84": "T",     "85": "U",    
"86": "V",     "87": "W",     "88": "X",     "89": "Y",     "90": "Z",    
"91": "[",     "92": "\\",    "93": "]",     "94": "^",     "95": "_",    
"96": "`",     "97": "a",     "98": "b",     "99": "c",     "100": "d",    
"101": "e",    "102": "f",    "103": "g",    "104": "h",    "105": "i",    
"106": "j",    "107": "k",    "108": "l",    "109": "m",    "110": "n",    
"111": "o",    "112": "p",    "113": "q",    "114": "r",    "115": "s",    
"116": "t",    "117": "u",    "118": "v",    "119": "w",    "120": "x",    
"121": "y",    "122": "z",    "123": "{",    "124": "|",    "125": "}",    
"126": "~",    "127": ""
}
```

Comment: Better ascii reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII - I'm pretty proud the coloring I did for the tables on that page remains there after almost 10 years : )

Comment: @theGrayFox `C:\> man ascii` gives `Bad command or file name`

Comment: Note that these methods are UTF-16 compatible, meaning depending on the input string, charCodeAt can extend far past 1 byte ASCII values 0-127.  Don't assume it is in that range if arbitrary string input is being accepted and handled by javascript.

Comment: @e2-e4 dear Developer your on the wrong OS. man is a linux command. Not sure of the windows equivalent. Probably safer using a search engine on a browser to search for 'man ascii' on windows, one result -> https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ascii.7.html

Answer (score 64):

If you have only one char and not a string, you can use:

```
'\n'.charCodeAt();
'\n'.codePointAt();
```

omitting the 0...

It used to be significantly slower than `'n'.charCodeAt(0)`, but I've tested it now and I do not see any difference anymore (executed 10 billions times with and without the 0). Tested for performance only in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: This actually takes longer. It's faster to just use the zero. (On my computer, it took ~twice as long—0.055s vs. 0.126s through a few ten thousand iterations)

Answer (score 33):

While the other answers are right, I prefer this way:

```
function ascii (a) { return a.charCodeAt(0); }
```

Then, to use it, simply:

```
var lineBreak = ascii("\n");
```

I am using this for a small shortcut system:

```
$(window).keypress(function(event) {
  if (event.ctrlKey && event.which == ascii("s")) {
    savecontent();
    }
  // ...
  });
```

And you can even use it inside map() or other methods:

```
var ints = 'ergtrer'.split('').map(ascii);
```

Comment: Just for the beauty a new ES6 way to write it:

```const ascii = a => a.charCodeAt(0);```

Answer (score 30):

For those that want to get a sum of all the ASCII codes for a string:

```
'Foobar'
  .split('')
  .map(char => char.charCodeAt(0))
  .reduce((current, previous) => previous + current)
```

Or, ES6:

```
[...'Foobar']
  .map(char => char.charCodeAt(0))
  .reduce((current, previous) => previous + current)
```

Comment: Double-check your last line.

Comment: Elegant! as a function:
        function ascii(str) {
            return str
                  .split('')
                  .map(function (char) {
                      return char + ": " + String(char.charCodeAt(0)) + "\n";
                  })
                  .reduce(function (current, previous) {
                      return current + previous;
                  });
        }

Comment: `[...'Foobar'].reduce((i,s)=>s.charCodeAt(0)+i,0)`

Answer (score 14):

To ensure full Unicode support and reversibility, consider using:

```
'\n'.codePointAt(0);
```

This will ensure that when testing characters over the UTF-16 limit, you will get their true code point value.

e.g.

```
''.codePointAt(0); // 68181
String.fromCodePoint(68181); // ''

''.charCodeAt(0);  // 55298
String.fromCharCode(55298);  // '�'
```

Comment: It might also be useful to convert the special character to hex notation, since some text editors might not work properly having to deal directly with such characters. EG:  

alert(str.hexEncode().hexDecode());

Answer (score 13):

Converting string into array(stream) of UTF-8:

```js
const str_to_arr_of_UTF8 = new TextEncoder().encode("Adfgdfs");
// [65, 100, 102, 103, 100, 102, 115]
```

**Note**: ASCII is a subset of UTF-8, so this is a universal solution

Answer (score 11):

JavaScript stores strings as `UTF-16` (double byte) so if you want to ignore the second byte just strip it out with a bitwise `&` operator on `0000000011111111` (ie 255):

```
'a'.charCodeAt(0) & 255 === 97; // because 'a' = 97 0 
'b'.charCodeAt(0) & 255 === 98; // because 'b' = 98 0 
'✓'.charCodeAt(0) & 255 === 19; // because '✓' = 19 39
```

Comment: why would you want to ignore the second byte?

Comment: Question is asking about producing ASCII from a UTF-16 string (double byte). Sooner or later you will get non-ascii codes if you fail to ignore the second byte.

Comment: @Steven de Salas - Your 'solution' to getting non-ASCII codes for non-ASCII characters is to return the **wrong** ASCII code??

Comment: @CarlSmith, not the wrong one. Just to strip out the non-ascii component of the character. If you are working with single bytes this is useful. Your project might need a different solution though.

Answer (score 6):

## As of 2023

### From character to ASCII code

Use the method [`charCodeAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt)

```js
console.log("\n".charCodeAt())
```

### From ASCII code to character

Use the method [`fromCharCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode)

```js
console.log(String.fromCharCode(10))
```

Comment: This doesn't support non-BMP Unicode characters as you would expect.

Comment: This was not part of the question

Comment: The question was about how to convert a character to its ASCII code. Your answer only works for some characters, not all characters.

Answer (score 4):

To convert a String to a cumulative number:

```js
const stringToSum = str => [...str||"A"].reduce((a, x) => a += x.codePointAt(0), 0);

console.log(stringToSum("A"));              // 65
console.log(stringToSum("Roko"));           // 411
console.log(stringToSum("Stack Overflow")); // 1386
```

### Use case:

Say you want to generate different background colors depending on a username:

```js
const stringToSum = str => [...str||"A"].reduce((a, x) => a += x.codePointAt(0), 0);

const UI_userIcon = user => {
  const hue = (stringToSum(user.name) - 65) % 360; // "A" = hue: 0
  console.log(`Hue: ${hue}`);
  return `<div class="UserIcon" style="background:hsl(${hue}, 80%, 60%)" title="${user.name}">
    <span class="UserIcon-letter">${user.name[0].toUpperCase()}</span>
  </div>`;
};

[
  {name:"A"},
  {name:"Amanda"},
  {name:"amanda"},
  {name:"Anna"},
].forEach(user => {
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", UI_userIcon(user));
});
```

```css
.UserIcon {
  width: 4em;
  height: 4em;
  border-radius: 4em;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.UserIcon-letter {
  font: 700 2em/0 sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Why the number "65"? What does that represent?

Comment: `-65` is totally optional. Since ASCII "A" character numeric = `65`. - 65 is optional, serves to get the first ("A") character as int `0`.

Answer (score 3):

You can enter a character and get Ascii Code Using this Code

For Example Enter a Character Like A 
You Get Ascii Code 65

```js
function myFunction(){
    var str=document.getElementById("id1");
    if (str.value=="") {
       str.focus();
       return;
    }
    var a="ASCII Code is == >  ";
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =a+str.value.charCodeAt(0);
}
```

```html
<p>Check ASCII code</p>

<p>
  Enter any character:  
  <input type="text" id="id1" name="text1" maxLength="1"> </br>
</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Get ASCII code</button>

<p id="demo" style="color:red;"></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

For supporting all UTF-16 (also [non-BMP/supplementary characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane)) from ES6 the [string.codePointAt()](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-string.prototype.charcodeat) method is available;

This method is an improved version of charCodeAt which could support only  unicode codepoints < 65536 ( 2<sup>16</sup> - a single 16bit ) .

Comment: It is worth mentioning that `String.prototype.codePointAt()` is [not supported by _any_ versions of Internet Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/codepointat-method-string-javascript). (However it is supported on Edge.) You can get a polyfill [here](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/String.prototype.codePointAt).

Answer (score 2):

```
str.charCodeAt(index)
```

Using `charCodeAt()`
The following example returns 65, the Unicode value for `A`.

`'ABC'.charCodeAt(0)`  ***// returns 65***

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the comments by [Álvaro González](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13508/%C3%81lvaro-gonz%C3%A1lez) and others, [charCodeAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) or [codePointAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/codePointAt) are mighty fine if you are working with the 128 original ASCII characters only (codes 0 to 127). Outside of this range, **the code is dependent on the character set**, and you need a charset conversion before calculating it if you want the result to make sense.

Let's take the Euro sign as an example: `'€'.codePointAt(0)` returns `8364`, which is well outside the 0-127 range and is relative to the UTF-16 (or [UTF-8](https://www.charset.org/utf-8/9)) charset.

I was porting a Visual Basic program, and noticed that it made use of the `Asc` function to get the character code. Obviously from its point of view, it would return the character code in the [Windows-1252](https://www.charset.org/charsets/windows-1252) character set. To be sure to obtain the same number, I need to convert the string charset and then calculate the code.

Pretty straightforward e.g. in Python: `ord('€'.encode('Windows-1252'))`.
To achieve the same in Javascript, however, I had to resort to buffers and a [conversion library](https://github.com/ashtuchkin/iconv-lite):

```
iconv = require('iconv-lite');
buf = iconv.encode("€", 'win1252');
buf.forEach(console.log);
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to get a sum of all the ASCII codes for a string with average value:

```js
const ASCIIAverage = (str) =>Math.floor(str.split('').map(item => item.charCodeAt(0)).reduce((prev,next) => prev+next)/str.length)

console.log(ASCIIAverage('Hello World!'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
charCodeAt(0);
```

Above code works in most cases, however there is a catch when working with words to find a ranking based on above code. For example, aa would give a ranking of 97+97 = 194 (actual would be 1+1 = 2) whereas w would give 119 (actual would be 23) which makes aa > w.
To fix this subtract 96 from above result, to start he positioning from 1.

```html
charCodeAt(0) - 96;
```

Comment: What about `alphabetically first` and `later`? I would recommend against using the sum of character codes for ranking and instead compare each character directly.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, ASCII only covers 128 characters (including non-printing characters). Unicode includes ASCII as its first 128 characters for the purpose of backwards compatibility, but it also includes far more characters.

To get *only* ASCII character codes as integers, you can do the following:

```js
function ascii_code (character) {
  
  // Get the decimal code
  let code = character.charCodeAt(0);

  // If the code is 0-127 (which are the ASCII codes,
  if (code < 128) {
    
    // Return the code obtained.
    return code;

  // If the code is 128 or greater (which are expanded Unicode characters),
  }else{

    // Return -1 so the user knows this isn't an ASCII character.
    return -1;
  };
};
```

If you're looking for *only* the ASCII characters in a string (for say, slugifying a string), you could do something like this:

```js
function ascii_out (str) {
  // Takes a string and removes non-ASCII characters.

  // For each character in the string,
  for (let i=0; i < str.length; i++) {

    // If the character is outside the first 128 characters (which are the ASCII
    // characters),
    if (str.charCodeAt(i) > 127) {

      // Remove this character and all others like it.
      str = str.replace(new RegExp(str[i],"g"),'');

      // Decrement the index, since you just removed the character you were on.
      i--;
    };
  };
  return str
};
```

#### Sources

- [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ascii-vs-unicode/#:~:text=Unicode%20is%20the%20universal%20character,encoding%20standard%20for%20electronic%20communication](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ascii-vs-unicode/#:%7E:text=Unicode%20is%20the%20universal%20character,encoding%20standard%20for%20electronic%20communication).
- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_charcodeat.asp

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can be also useful (ascii characters in the order like in the ascii table):

```
let ascii_chars = "";
for (let i = 32; i <= 126; ++i) {
    ascii_chars += String.fromCharCode(i);
}
document.write(ascii_chars);
```