# How to get the ASCII value in JavaScript for the characters

Tags: javascript, char, ascii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert character to ASCII code in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94037/convert-character-to-ascii-code-in-javascript)

my requirement is to get the ASCII value of the alphabet letters... Can anyone suggest how to do this in JavaScript?

Comment: have you done some search before posting. check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94037/convert-character-to-ascii-code-in-javascript)

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Here is the example:

```js
var charCode = "a".charCodeAt(0);
console.log(charCode);
```

Or if you have longer strings:

```js
var string = "Some string";

for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
  console.log(string.charCodeAt(i));
}
```

`String.charCodeAt(x)` method will return ASCII character code at a given position.

Comment: This is Unicode, not ASCII!!! http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_charcodeat.asp

Answer (score 7):

you can try

```
"str".charCodeAt(0)
```

Comment: @Andrew ASCII is a subset of Unicode, so it's actually the same in this case. (Actually, Unicode is not an encoding, and ASCII is, so in that sense they are different. But for the purposes of `charCodeAt`, there's no difference).

Comment: This won't work. it will take only 's'