# Get JavaScript to ignore everything that is not a letter

Tags: javascript

How would I get JS to ignore everything that is not a letter (e.g. abc...) **without using regex**.

```
Examples
match("abcdef","@C2D!") returns true
match("abcdef","CAfe") returns true
match("abcdef","CG") returns false
```

This is what I've done so far...

```
function match(string, pattern) {
    string = string.toLowerCase();
    pattern = pattern.toLowerCase();
    for (var i = 0, l = string.length; i < l; ++i) {
        if(pattern.indexOf(string[i]) === -1) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
alert(match("abcdef", "@C2D!"));
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/5UCwW/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3073176/1636522, in your case : `!/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test('@C2D!')`.

Comment: I find it really hard to understand the requirement. The string value `abcdef` always consists of just letters and it seems to match none of the pattern you pass in. Can you elaborate on the requirement a bit?

Comment: Is it possible to do it without regex

Comment: If you don't want to use a part of the language, at least try to explain why so.

Comment: "without regex", better to mention it inside the question.

Comment: Question updated - not allowed to use regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression like the following `[^A-Za-z]`.

```
var re = /[^A-Za-z]/g;

function match(string, pattern) {
    string = string.toLowerCase();
    pattern = pattern.toLowerCase().replace(re, "");
    for (var i = 0, l = string.length; i < l; ++i) {
        if(pattern.indexOf(string[i]) === -1) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**As a function without reg ex**

```
var sanitize = function (str) { 
  var newStr = "", i, charCode;

  for (i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) {
    charCode = str.charCodeAt(i);  
    if (charCode >= 65 && charCode <= 90 ||
        charCode >= 97 && charCode <= 122)  {
      newStr += str[i];
    } 

  return newStr;
}
```

EDIT: A-z uses the range of the ascii values from capital a to small case z. Thus this includes ], \, [, ^, _ and `. I was not aware of this, [A-Za-z] is the correct pattern.

Comment: Can it be placed within a function?

Comment: `\w` includes digits and underscore; nowhere in the question the OP mentions these shouldn't be ignored. Also, `[^\w]` is the same as just `\W`.

Comment: Yupp you guys are corret, fixed my answer to reflect it.

Comment: `[A-z]` is not the same as `[A-Za-z]`.

Comment: @raina77ow I figured that out, thanks for telling me though. I didn't know that. I guess I am one of todays luck 10000 :)

Comment: Of course it can, but why would you want to do that? The simple solution is to just loop over all characters in the string and check their ascii values.

Comment: @HugoTunius sounds like what I need, how would you go about doing that?

Comment: Loop through the string and check if the ascii value is in the range 65-90 or 97-122. TO get the ascii value look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10879244/how-to-get-the-ascii-value-in-javascript-for-the-characters

Comment: Thanks - can the answer take the form `function match(string, pattern)`

Comment: Just use the sanitize after you have made the pattern lowercase.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40903/discussion-between-hugo-tunius-and-antoine-laurent-lavoisier)

Answer (score 1):

Use Javascript's built-in match method on strings:

```
 var mystring = '@C2D!';
 mystring.match(/[^a-zA-Z]/gi).length returns true
```

and

```
 var mystring2 = 'abcdef';
 mystring2.match(/[^a-zA-Z]/gi).length returns false
```

I'm assuming you're looking for lower and upper-case letters.  If just lower, use [^a-z].

For more info on the match method, go here:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp