# javascript convert character to key code

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert character to ASCII code in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94037/convert-character-to-ascii-code-in-javascript)

How can I convert any character to the key code  like

```
m    77
n    78
o    79
p    80
q    81
r    82
s    83
t    84
u    85
v    86
```

Comment: `character.charCodeAt(0) - 32`

Answer (score 1):

```
var alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split(''),
    len = alphabet.length,
    i;

for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    console.log(alphabet[i], alphabet[i].charCodeAt(0) - 32);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/n2ZFa/

Comment: `'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('').forEach(function(c){console.log(c.charCodeAt(0))});`