# Simple ascii replacement - Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for a javascript function which takes a string parameter and checks for ascii characters lower than 32, replacing them with empty string -> "". I'm new to javascript so I was wondering whether anyone can point me towards the right direction ?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Also, why? Might be a better way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94037/convert-character-to-ascii-code-in-javascript

this may help

Comment: What I meant was, I want to find and remove any characters within the string that has a lower ascii value than 32

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
var replaced = string.replaceAll("[^ -~]", "");
```

Using `^` negates the characters class, and since space is character 32 in the ASCII table and ~ is the last printable character, you're basically saying "everything that isn't a printable character".

To simply remove all characters from 0-31 use:

```
var replace = string.replaceAll("\x00-\x1F", "");
```

Comment: See my edit, I've included how to match specific character codes, with 1F being 31.

Comment: This will remove french letter `à`.

Comment: @Vitaly Not at desk ATM, which code is à? You could just add "^à" or "^{insert character code here}" to the regular expression to get it to exclude those from the replacement :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you are looking for a regex to use with .replace...

For replacing any printable ascii chars you can use this regex:

```
/[ -~]/
```

You will probably have to adjust the range. I recommend changing the tilder since it is the last printable char.

**Sorry, I see what you mean! I think you cannot match unprintable chars unless use use their special symbol: i.e. \b \s \n etc.**

Answer (score 1):

```
function keepCharsAbove(inStr, charCode) {
  var goodChars = [];
  for(var x = 0; x < inStr.length; x++) {
      if(inStr.charCodeAt(x) > charCode) {
          goodChars.push(inStr.charAt(x));
      }
  }

  return goodChars.join("");
}
```

​
Usage:

```
keepCharsAbove("foo \t bar",32); // returns 'foobar'
```

Comment: This would probably be better by converting the input to an array of single character strings, filtering the array (`Array.filter`) and then joining back into a string. (A more functional approach.)