# How to change specific ASCII Charfacter to space character before submit a form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below code to recognize the special ASCII codes before submit the form. How can I set condition to change that ASCII codes with character space? For example, I don't want the user enter **;** and I want to change this character with space.

Here is my code :

```js
function isNumberKey(evt) {
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
  if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48))
    return true;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="#">
  <input name="mastername" type="text" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Simple ascii replacement - Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13398369/simple-ascii-replacement-javascript) ?

Comment: @roetnig i want to do this with jquery

Comment: @roetnig and i want to replace with specific ascii code

Comment: And what's the problem ? jquery is just a javascript library

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cancel the keydown in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3036243/cancel-the-keydown-in-html)