# How to create a table of conversion from url encoded chars to char ASCII code?

Tags: javascript, url-rewriting, ascii

I have tried to create one by hand with some basic char codes:

```
    /*       0  1  2  3   4  5  6  7   8  9  A  B   C  D  E  F */
    /* 0 */ -1,-1,-1,-1, -1,-1,-1,-1, -1,-1,-1,-1, -1,-1,-1,-1,
    /* 1 */ -1,-1,-1,-1, -1,-1,-1,-1, -1,-1,-1,-1, -1,-1,-1,-1,
    /* 2 */ -1,-1,-1,-1, -1,-1,-1,-1, -1,-1,-1,-1, -1,-1,-1,-1,
    /* 3 */  0, 1, 2, 3,  4, 5, 6, 7,  8, 9,-1,-1, -1,-1,-1,-1,

    /* 4 */ -1,10,11,12, 13,14,15,-1, -1,-1,-1,-1, -1,-1,-1,-1,
    /* 5 */ -1,-1,-1,-1, -1,-1,-1,-1, -1,-1,-1,-1, -1,-1,-1,-1,
    /* 6 */ -1,10,11,12, 13,14,15,-1, -1,-1,-1,-1, -1,-1,-1,-1,
    /* 7 */ -1,-1,-1,-1, -1,-1,-1,-1, -1,-1,-1,-1, -1,-1,-1,-1,

    /* 8 */ -1,-1,-1,-1, -1,-1,-1,-1, -1,-1,-1,-1, -1,-1,-1,-1,
    /* 9 */ -1,-1,-1,-1, -1,-1,-1,-1, -1,-1,-1,-1, -1,-1,-1,-1,
    /* A */ -1,-1,-1,-1, -1,-1,-1,-1, -1,-1,-1,-1, -1,-1,-1,-1,
    /* B */ -1,-1,-1,-1, -1,-1,-1,-1, -1,-1,-1,-1, -1,-1,-1,-1,

    /* C */ -1,-1,-1,-1, -1, -1,-1,-1, -1,-1,-1,-1, -1,-1,-1,-1,
    /* D */ -1,-1,-1,-1, -1,-1,-1,-1, -1,-1,-1,-1, -1,-1,-1,-1,
    /* E */ -1,-1,-1,-1, -1,-1,-1,-1, -1,-1,-1,-1, -1,-1,-1,-1,
    /* F */ -1,-1,-1,-1, -1,-1,-1,-1, -1,-1,-1,-1, -1,-1,-1,-1
```

but wonder how to create filled table in automated way using javascript (there is nice [to ASCII code sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9539389/1056328) I found but I do not get how to iterate over url encoded symbols)?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need a table? Decoding, like encoding, is built-in:

```
var decoded = decodeURIComponent(encoded);
```

(If you're not actually trying to decode a URL-encoded string, but rather absolutely need the table, then you can just iterate through and use `decodeURIComponent` by prepending a `%`.)