# Scroll to person name on a webpage if first letter of name is pressed on keyboard

Tags: php, jquery, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, usability

I have a page with a list of about 500 names.
The user would like to type for e.g. `s` on their keyboard and then the page will automatically scroll to the names starting with `s`.

Should I convert the first letter of those names to an `INT`, give that INT as a data-attribute and add a jQuery function to the page or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest to embed the list of names for each character in a div with the appropriate `id`, such as for the names starting with *S*:

```
<div id="S">
  ... names with S ...
</div>
```

Then you can use jQuery to react on a keypress, and just do a

```
location.href = '#S';
```

Then, the browser will automatically scroll to the appropriate `div`. Another advantage of this is that you can even use the URL to put it into your favorites, so if you want to jump directly to all people with *S*, you can do this easily.

**Update:** As the `.keypress()` function of jQuery only returns a number, not the character itself, you need to convert it. See [Convert character to ASCII code in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9539389/1333873) for an example of how to convert a character to a number and vice-versa.

Comment: But jQuery keypress will return an integer, not a letter.

Comment: So what? The number is the ASCII code (IIRC), so you can easily convert it to the appropriate character.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for something a bit faster, you can do the following trick (I presume the names are ordered).

You add to the first element that has a certain letter the `id="letter_X"`, and when the user scrolls, you just use the id as an anchor (`my_url#letter_X`).

This is the fastest way I know for doing this, but works for only one letter.

PS: in html5 anchors are now element ids, and can be added on any html element.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use section with an id for the tag. then do a $.scrollTop() from jquery.

```
$(window).scrollTop($('section#user_id').offset().top);
```