# Get string from a list contain Unicode in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, list, unicode, fromcharcode

I have a list of Unicode values `[65, 66, 67]` and I want the corresponding string `"ABC"`. I looked into the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) and found the function `String.fromCharCode()`that does what I need to do. The only problem is that the arguments needs to be *a sequence of numbers*.

So if I use `String.fromCharCode([65, 66, 67])` it gives me `" "`.

Is there a way **that allows the *list* to be treated as *a sequence* for a function**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert character to ASCII code in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94037/convert-character-to-ascii-code-in-javascript)

Comment: You mentioned "unicode". If you want to support more than just ISO/IEC-8859-1 (aka ASCII + table for upper half of byte), use [`String.fromCodePoint(unicodeValue)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to spread the array using `...` `spread` ***Syntax***.

```js
console.log(String.fromCharCode(...[65, 66, 67]));
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

> Spread syntax allows an iterable such as an array expression to be
>   expanded in places where zero or more arguments (for function calls)
>   or elements (for array literals) are expected, or an object expression
>   to be expanded in places where zero or more key-value pairs (for
>   object literals) are expected.

Comment: To nitpick, [`...` is not an operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44934830/1541563)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Thanks Patrick for pointing that, Multiple website does mention the use of Spread Operator. However, MDN does mention it as **Syntax**, i will check the link and the specification.

Answer (score 2):

Map on the list and then join:

```js
var s = [65, 66, 67].map(x => String.fromCharCode(x)).join("");
console.log(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
/* You can map over the list and the value you need will be output to anoter list */
var charCodes = [65, 66, 67],
    stringsFromCharCodes = charCodes.map(item => String.fromCharCode(item));

console.log('new list: ', stringsFromCharCodes);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use apply to solve this

```js
var chars = [65,66,67]
var s = String.fromCharCode.apply({}, chars)
console.log(s);
```